# safely round-trip integers values with IEEE 754 floating point double precision data type

Tags: c++, floating-point

C++ standard guarantee us that we can only safely round-trip decimal values with up to
for `double` value `std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10`. 
After reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20849674/is-double-guaranteed-by-c03-to-represent-small-integers-exactly), I'm wondering if for integers values this threshold it extends to `std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10`+1

Comment: The C++ standard and IEEE 754 are unrelated.

Comment: @n.m. Note entirely. C++ defines `std::numeric_limits<double>::is_iec559` (or something like that) which tells if the implementation is complying with IEEE 754. If that's true, then it's certainly valid to ask how to get C++ operators to generate 754 operations which are suitable to a particular purpose.

Comment: std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10+1 is 16, and you can't round-trip all 16-digit integers (e.g., 9007199254740993 comes back as 9007199254740992).

Comment: @RickRegan: You should enter that as an answer. (With an additional qualification that the counterexample is using IEEE-754 64-bit binary floating-point for the `double` type.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

std::numeric_limits::digits10 is 15 because only values that are 15 digits or less are guaranteed to round-trip from decimal to double-precision and back. Some 16-digit values will round-trip, but not all of them. In the case of integers, only those <= 2^53 = 9007199254740992 are guaranteed to round-trip (because they are represented exactly). 9007199254740993, for example, comes back as 9007199254740992.

Comment: Note that only the odd numbers have problems, even numbers are OK until you get to 18014398509481984.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes, that's a much better way to put it. That sounds less mysterious than "some 16-digit values will round-trip, but not all of them".